# Wrapping an unchecked exception into a checked exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am reading code written by others. Both unchecked exception and checked exception are custom exceptions. I see that an unchecked exception is thrown inside a method and it is wrapped into checked exception in a catch clause and thrown again. It is a common practice to wrap an unchecked exception into a checked exception? If yes, why do we do that?

Comment: One reason I could think of is if you don't want to deal with the exception yourself, but you want to force the caller to deal with it. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom unchecked exceptions are a culprit in ["leaky abstractions."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction)

An application might define an interface for a service that it depends on. If the implementation throws implementation-specific unchecked exceptions that the application would like to handle specifically, it becomes polluted with implementation-specific exception types. This causes a maintenance headache if the implementation is replaced.

To avoid this problem, the unchecked exceptions might be wrapped in implementation-neutral checked exceptions defined by the interface.

As a concrete example, consider Hibernate's use of unchecked exceptions to notify callers of constraint violations. Suppose you have a `User` entity and the user name has a unique constraint defined in the database. You'd like to handle this condition specially, by prompting the user for a different name. If Hibernate's `ConstraintViolationException` propagates unchanged up the stack, the application will need Hibernate-specific handlers. On the other hand, if the data access layer wraps this in a suitable custom checked exception, replacing Hibernate with a new ORM implementation won't require any changes beyond the implementation layer.

Comment: It's a great answer to my generic question. Thanks. I would like to give you more details. In a service delegate class, it throws an unchecked exception and the method that calls this delegate re-throws it as a checked exception. Both  unchecked and checked exceptions are application defined custom exceptions. Is it a good practice?

Comment: The method in the service delegate class is being called in several places. So, the unchecked exception thrown in the delegate class is ignored in some places and it is re-thrown as a checked exception in some places. So, I I am kind of confused with the usage.

Comment: It could be okay. That is, perhaps the caller that is doing the wrapping (in some cases) has some context to distinguish unchecked and checked exceptions. The rule of thumb is that unchecked exceptions should be the the result of a programming error by the caller, as opposed to environmental problems or data-driven problems. If these custom unchecked exceptions don't fit that criterion, I'd be a lot more suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

If you do that in a method `meth` it is probably because the code calling
`meth` will need to only know about and check for the checked exception.
Say if `meth` can throw 5 different types of unchecked exceptions,
you make this more uniform and allow the calling code to worry only
about the checked one. But of course you can use unchecked exception
for this wrapping too. It is just that the compiler won't be able to
help you much in the calling code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Peter. You answered it from a different aspect. I assume that I can only able to select one for as an answer. I don't know well rules in the forum.

Comment: No problem. You select whichever you like most :) Good luck.